# How do I use an ME interface terminal with my patterns?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have set up a working ME network with drives to store my items. I have a few patterns I want to use for crafting but my ME Interface Terminal is completely white.

My pattern is in the storage on the drives but it is not being detected by the ME Interface Terminal. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ME interface Terminal](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface-Terminal/) shows you all your [ME Interfaces](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface/) on the network. If it's white, and the network is working, I'd guess you do not have any. The network will not perform crafting from [Encoded Patterns](https://ae-mod.info/Encoded-Pattern/) just sitting in storage, you need to set them up on [ME Interface](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface/) on relevant crafting machines.

In order to set up basic crafting on ME you'll need to do the following:

1. Place a [ME Interface](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface/) on a crafting machine.

   - In case of a crafting pattern, the machine is a [Molecular Assembler Chamber (MAC)](https://ae-mod.info/Molecular-Assembler/).
   - In case of a processing pattern, the machine is the machine capable of performing the processing, e.g. a furnace.
2. Craft a [Blank Pattern](https://ae-mod.info/Blank-Pattern/) and [encode](https://ae-mod.info/Encoded-Pattern/) it with the desired recipe in a [ME Pattern Terminal](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Pattern-Terminal/).
3. Put the [Encoded Pattern](https://ae-mod.info/Encoded-Pattern/) in the [ME Interface](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface/). This can be done via the [ME Interface Terminal](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface-Terminal/), or you can just place it there by hand.
4. Build a [Crafting CPU](https://ae-mod.info/Crafting-CPU/) somewhere in the network to manage the crafting. For a start, a simple [1k Crafting Storage](https://ae-mod.info/1k-Crafting-Storage/) should be enough.
5. Make sure the [ME Interface](https://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface/) and the [1k Crafting Storage](https://ae-mod.info/1k-Crafting-Storage/) both have a [channel](https://ae-mod.info/Channels/), the [MAC](https://ae-mod.info/Molecular-Assembler/) only needs power (no channel), the network has power and is working, there are crafting components available, etc.
6. Order crafting. Enjoy!